# FBSDKLoginButton with native iOS dialog

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.x, fbsdk

I have my login button setup like this.

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
loginButton.loginBehavior = 0; // native
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

What I wish to have is a native login dialog instead of the web view one, so I assign the loginBehavior to 0, as specified in this enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSDKLoginBehavior) {
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative = 0,
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser,
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount,
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb,
};
```

However, no matter what behavior I set, I only get web view login.

I am running my app in a real iOS device, with Facebook app installed and authenticated.

I notice apps such as Tinder, or Instagram have their own native login dialogs. Is this a misconfiguration from my part?

Comment: This is most likely to happen on iOS 9. Have you checked on other versions as well?

Comment: Not yet. I'll have to find an iOS 8 phone.

Comment: I am thinking that even if this is the case, why are the other apps able to use native dialog in my phone?

Comment: Well, I use the FBSDKLoginButton in my app and the same is happening. I am guessing the other apps have a custom login flow and do not use FBSDKLoginButton.

Comment: Also you should specify enum values with their descriptive name, not values. `loginButton.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;`. Just improves readability.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with bundleID, since that's how it can detect the presence of the native Facebook app. I updated the bundleID accordingly but it is no help.

Comment: Did you guys find a solution?

Comment: There is no solution to find, since this is by design :)
It has been confirmed that this is a new change introduced in the latest SDK [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/49).